Apps Script Mailapp.sendEmail not working from Google Workspace account
We are a non-profit Organisation that has been using Sheets, Forms and Apps Script, some of which send out emails using MailApp.sendEmail() from a standard Google account for a number of years with no problem.
We have now obtained a Google Workspace account with the intent to migrate our operational sheets/forms/scripts to the new Workspace as Google Workspace has much higher account limits.  One of the first things we have tried, is to test out the script mailing functionality and it simply does not work from any of our Google Workspace accounts.  Note general user emails are working fine from within our workspace account as we have sent many from various internal accounts i.e. our general email set-up is functional.
Below is a simple code block that we used to test.  In order to provide more information, the script tries to send a test email to four separate email accounts - two external mail accounts using different destination mail servers and two google accounts, one internal to the workspace domain and one external (@gmail.com).  The script executes fine, the email appears in the sent folder of the sending account (the one running the script), but nothing arrives at any of the destinations.  The code is shown below (with email addresses changed for security):
function testEmail() {
  Logger.log('testEmail START');
  var address = 'firstexternal@domain.com,secondexternal@anotherdomain.com,personalemail@gmail.com,testaccount@ourworkspacedomain.com';
  
  // Create the html version of the response email    
  var html_mailBody = 'Hello this is a test email<br><br>';

  // Create the text version of the response email
  var text_mailBody = 'Hello this is a test email\n\n';
  
  // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: address,
    subject: "Test Email to three different recipients",
    body: text_mailBody,
    htmlBody: html_mailBody
  });
  Logger.log('testEmail END');
}

In trying to investigate further, we looked at the email logs in our Google Workspace Admin Console and what we see is the the email is listed as "bounced" for each of the recipient addresses and "delivered to Gmail mailbox" for the sender i.e. placed in the Sent folder.  Upon expanding the logs for the bounced mails all we see are "delivered to an SMTP server" immediately followed by "bounced".  There are no details of server addresses and as no actual bounce message is received, we have no email headers to look at for bounced messages.
We have looked on the web and have found a few references to this type of behaviour but the only "answer" seems to be "use GmailApp instead" which we're sure will work but we'd expect to see more "noise" if MailApp didn't work from a Google Workspace account so we suspect that we may have something set wrong in our Workspace Domain and we would prefer not to have to adjust our scripts when migrating.
We have reached out to Workspace support but we are going around in circles so thought we would see if anybody else has seen this or as a minimum, get confirmation that MailApp does currently work from A Google Workspace account.

This worked for me with 3 email addresses:
function testEmail() {
  var address = 'redacted';
  var html_mailBody = 'Hello this is a test email<br><br>';
  var text_mailBody = 'Hello this is a test email\n\n';
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: address,
    subject: "Test Email to three different recipients",
    body: text_mailBody,
    htmlBody: html_mailBody
  });
}


OK, thanks - useful to know that it works for you.  May I ask how long you have had your Workspace Account i.e. some time (was it a G-Suite account?) or relatively new?

Try using GmailApp instead of MailApp.

Your test email messages might be caught by measures to protect recipients from spam, especially if you use a new domain and MailApp.
Try using GmailApp instead of MailApp. This is based on years of experience in using Google Apps Script and participating in Stack Overflow on google-apps-script.
Another thing to try is changing the subject and body to make the message appear closer to the actual message. In the message body, include something that makes each message unique; it's better if both the subject and body are unique. One way is to include a timestamp. Your mileage might vary.
On the other hand, you should review whether the domain's SPF, DMARC and related email settings are properly set.

Thanks for the feedback.  I accept that GmailApp is probably the way to go but I didn't want to be migrating sheets/forms/scripts and modifying them at the same time, especially if it's just a case of a simple setting somewhere.

I have SPF, DKIM and DMARC set up and have been checking the daily DMARC reports - no errors so I believe I've got that right.
SPAM settings are an area I've considered but I've not spotted anything obvious.
Overall, if this should work, as Cooper's reply suggests, then I'd like to understand what's wrong rather than avoiding the issue - even if I use Gmail App going forwards, I hate not understanding what the issue is!
